# how to more than one module in laravel using array and forloop

Tags: php, laravel

```
$module_name = array(
    "Customerdetails",
    "Customercomments",
    "Complaints",
    "Customerquotes",
    "Systemconfiguration",
    "regulatoryreports",
    "Customermain",
    "Customerdomestic"
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($module_name); $i++) {
    $row = DB::table('tb_module')->where('module_name', $module_name[$i])->get();
    if (count($row) <= 0) {
        return Redirect::to('/Grouplevel')
            ->with('message', SiteHelpers::alert('error', 'Can not find module'));
    }
    //print_r($row);

    $row = $row[0];
    $row_name[$i] = $row;
    $module[$i] = $this->module;
    $config = SiteHelpers::CF_decode_json($row->module_config);
    $tasks = array(
        'is_view' => 'View ',
        'is_detail' => 'Detail',
        'is_add' => 'Add ',
        'is_edit' => 'Edit ',
        'is_remove' => 'Remove ',
    );
    /* Update permission global / own access new ver 1.1
       Adding new param is_global
       End Update permission global / own access new ver 1.1
    */
    if (isset($config['tasks'])) {
        foreach ($config['tasks'] as $row) {
            $tasks[$row['item']] = $row['title'];
        }
    }
    $this->data['tasks'] = $tasks;
    $this->data['groups'] = DB::table('tb_groups')->get();

    $access = array();

    foreach ($this->data['groups'] as $r) {
        //  $GA = $this->model->gAccessss($this->uri->rsegment(3),$row['group_id']);
        $group = ($r->group_id != null ? "and group_id ='" . $r->group_id . "'" : "");
        $GA = DB::select("SELECT * FROM tb_groups_access where module_id ='" . $row->module_id . "' $group");
        if (count($GA) >= 1) {
            $GA = $GA[0];
        }

        $access_data = (isset($GA->access_data) ? json_decode($GA->access_data, true) : array());
        $rows = array();
        //$access_data = json_decode($AD,true);
        $rows[$i]['group_id'] = $r->group_id;
        $rows[$i]['group_name'] = $r->name;
        foreach ($tasks as $item => $val) {
            $rows[$i][$item] = (isset($access_data[$item]) && $access_data[$item] == 1 ? 1 : 0);
        }
        $access[$r->name] = $rows[$i];
        $id[$i] = $row->module_id;
    }
}

for ($i = 0; $i < count($module_name); $i++) {
    $this->data['row'] = $row_name[$i];
    $this->data['module'] = $module[$i];
    $this->data['module_name'] = $row_name[$i]->module_name;
    $this->data['access'] = $access;
    $this->data['groups_access'] = DB::select("select * from tb_groups_access where module_id ='" . $id[$i] . "'");
    $this->layout->nest('content', 'Grouplevel.index', $this->data)
        ->with('menus', SiteHelpers::menus());
}
```

Comment: You are overwriting the data array rather than appending to it, hence it prints the last item

Comment: i want to know how to append

Comment: You could try `$this->data['module'][$i] = $module[$i];`